# vue-cli@3 No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

when I used vue-cli@3 to

`npm run build`

system hint generate this error `No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency`

I have searched a lot of related questions, but they are all angular，And i also tried

1. rm -r node_modules
2. rm package-lock.json
3. npm i

But this error still occurs,I want to know how can I solve this problem

Here are the details of my error

```
ERROR  Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency
Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency
    at addDependency (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:800:12)
    at iterationOfArrayCallback (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:208:3)
    at addDependenciesBlock (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:816:5)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:827:4)
    at afterBuild (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:954:15)
    at buildModule.err (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:998:11)
    at callback (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:734:5)
    at module.build.error (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:782:12)
    at handleParseResult (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:478:12)
    at doBuild.err (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:500:6)
    at runLoaders (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12)
    at E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:186:6
    at context.callback (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at childCompiler.runAsChild (E:\Games\Hitokoto\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:198:12)
    at compile (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11)
    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at compilation.seal.err (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
E:\Games\hitokoto\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:16
    throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
```

Then below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "hitokoto",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.4.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had the same issue, and figured out it was related to the **upper/lower casing of the path used** when running the *npm run build* command.

Using either Powershell or cmd, I did this:

```
C:\> cd C:\git\testing
C:\git\testing> npm run build
```

and got the same error as you.

Then I did this (notice uppercase GIT):

```
C:\>cd C:\GIT\testing
C:\GIT\testing> npm run build
```

and then it worked. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: The same problem is indeed caused by the case of the path

Comment: I cannot believe this was the issue. So simple... Thank you so much!

Comment: Yet one more reason why Webpack is barely usable

Comment: May I ask how did you know which part of the path you need to change case to make it work?

Comment: The easiest way is just to use TAB completion when writing the 'cd' command, since it'll automatically suggest correct casing.

Comment: just for future checks, It didnt worked for me, testing in poweshell and gitbash, same behaviour, still looking how to get the build done =( thanks

Comment: My college ran into the same problem. This is a life saver solution!!!

Comment: Thanks to this answer I notice that the folder name was actually clientapp but on the .csproj file it has the node <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>.
As soon I change it to <SpaRoot>clientapp\</SpaRoot> it works.

Comment: This has solved in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

this may be caused by **MiniCssExtractPlugin** ,
it should be used both *module/rules* and *plugins*

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
//define module\rules
{
    test:/\.css$/, 
    use:[{loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader},{loader:'css-loader'}]
},

//set plugins
plugins:[
 new vueLoaderPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
]
```

more info see here: **https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/493**

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. this method worked for me. In your `vue.config.js` add this:

```
css: {
 extract: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I executed

> npm run build

from GIT bash and faced the issue. Probably due to file paths case (upper/lower) issue. I switched back to normal command line and it is working.